# Is it possible to check whether a password will be valid without creating an user on Windows?

Tags: windows, validation, passwords

I need to check if the password for an user that will be created later on in an installation process will be valid. That is, whether it will conform to the OS validation rules. Is there an API call to check if a given password will be valid? This is on Windows

Comment: This is a reasonable question if he's doing this programatically in an installer.

Comment: Correct, it is performed as part of an installer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [`NetValidatePasswordPolicy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370661%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

This can check against the local OS password policy too.

Comment: Thanks! It looks pretty promising, let me check if it will work for my case and report back. One concern is that it is supported only in server versions of Windows (2003 and up)

Comment: It seems it also supports Windows Vista and up (even if not documented) http://blogs.msdn.com/b/david_leblanc/archive/2007/10/11/checking-password-complexity.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 Help says that in password any characters can be used:
a..z
A..Z
0..9
` ~ ! @ # $ % ^ & * ( ) _ - + = { } [ ] \ | : ; " ' < > , . ? /
and space.

Read here: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows7/Tips-for-creating-strong-passwords-and-passphrases

Maybe it is possible to use regular expression to check the password.

Comment: That's passwords in general, but I think that he wants to check if a password meets the password complexity requirements set by the administrator.

Comment: Matteo is correct. Also requirements can be strengthened/relaxed by the admin, I need to check the password will be valid for a particular system